# After Angular upgrade to 16 , ng serve compilation fails with many errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular-cli, angular16, ng-upgrade

After Angular upgrade from 15 to 16.
Ng serve fails with typescript compilation errors from

```
 src/app/feature/videocall-activity-window/videocall-activity-window.component.html:2:38 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known 
property of 'div'.

 <div tabindex="0" id="vidPlayerComp" [ngStyle]="{'width': VideocontainerWidth+'px', 'height': VideocontainerHeight+'px'}">
```

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'applyClass' since it isn't a known property of 'svg-icon'.
1. If 'svg-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'applyClass' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'svg-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```